# Can I build a Java-based game and move it to Ubuntu for the future tablets and phones?

Tags: java, ubuntu-touch

I am on my way to learn Java game programming to make my own Android apps.  My question is if I can built a Java-based game and move it to Ubuntu for the future tablets and phones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu for phones won't accept Java apps. However you can run this app via Android SDK.

Comment: then what is the programming language make Ubuntu apps?

Comment: HTML+JS or QML+C++ - You can find tutorials here: http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/qml/tutorial/building_your_first_qml_app/

Comment: soooooooo if you run the ubuntu platform in the android sdk, this means that i can transport(convert) my java or android application to Ubuntu and then it will run.

Comment: No, I mean that if you really need to run Android app on Ubuntu desktop, you can do it via Android SDK.
It's not possible to run Android SDK on Ubuntu Mobile. As well as Ubuntu Mobile in Android SDK (or at least I haven't heard about trying to do it)